# Detect Swipe Even the Finger Hasn't been Released

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect the mouse swipe up and swipe down, I tried the script below but it only works:

1 - if the finger has been released between any two swipes.
2 - if the finger hasn't been released, but only if the second swipe has exceed the original finger position (firstPressPos).

**What I want exactly is:**

For example, I put my finger on the screen and I swipe down, then after I swipe up (without releasing the finger between the two swipes), I want to detect the two swipes in the real time.

How can I do that?

**Script:**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        firstPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    }

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        secondPressPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

        currentSwipe.Normalize();

        if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            //Swipe Up
        }

        if (currentSwipe.y < 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5f)
        {
            //Swipe Down
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a couple of flags to know which swipe status you're in if your are in one.

```
private bool _swiping;
private bool _swipingDown;
private Vector3 _previousSwipePosition;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        _previousSwipePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        _swiping = true;
        Debug.log("Started Swipe");
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        _swiping = false;
        Debug.log("Finished Swipe");
    }

    if (_swiping)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        if (newPosition.y < _previousSwipePosition.y)
        {
            if (!_swipingDown)
            {
                Debug.Log("Started Swipe Down");
                _swipingDown = true;
            }
        }
        if (newPosition.y> _previousSwipePosition.y)
        {
            if (_swipingDown)
            {
                Debug.Log("Started Swipe Up");
                _swipingDown = false;
            }
        }
        _previousSwipePosition = newPosition;
    }
}
```

This will let you know when a Swipe is Started, Finished and Changes direction using flags.

*flags - booleans to signify something*

Comment: Yes, but it detect the swipes only once, I want to detect swipe in each frame

Comment: Removing the `_swipingDown` flag will cause it to check every frame not just when a swipe is started.